# Click on a div that have the same class name than other divs with Selenium Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation, windows-10

greetings!

I'm new with Selenium. I would like to make click in a div which has the same class name than other divs. The class name is: answer wHGy3xn8heDaX4AOwXEmk _10bHElnyU5MzSMU2VKM4sp . I tried with:

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "answer wHGy3xn8heDaX4AOwXEmk _10bHElnyU5MzSMU2VKM4sp[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1gmc.png)").click()

and

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.answer:nth-child(2)").click()

and

allclasses = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "answer wHGy3xn8heDaX4AOwXEmk_10bHElnyU5MzSMU2VKM4sp")

allclasses[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xkx0.png).click()

But is not working.

Thank you so much for your kindly help!

When I clicked on the div, they change the class name to: answer wHGy3xn8heDaX4AOwXEmk _1z6aWtO0V6asN1r3PVNOYJ

[image]

[image]